# call by reference in functions

Tags: c++, function

I am practicing functions in `C++`. In some random notes, I found an example of functions call by value and call by reference.

The code is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void F1(float a, float b)
{
    a++;b++;
}

void F2 (float &a, float &b)
{
    a++;
    b++;
}
int main ()
{
    float a=9,b=5;

    float *ptrA=&a;
    float *ptrB=&b;

    F1(a,b);
    cout<<"\na:"<<a<<"\nb:"<<b;
    F2(a,b);
    cout<<"\na:"<<a<<"\nb:"<<b;
}
```

Now for the function F2, I am confused that in the main function I have passed the value of a and b and in the definition it received the address of the variable a and b. Then how will the increment be done in the values of a and b?

Comment: It might be worth you reading up on function scope and pointers, they can be tricky to get your head around but they are necessary to understand this particular point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```
F2(a,b);
```

Actually sends the addresses of a and b, and not their values, because of the way F2 is declared. In C++, references are like pointers, just with a cleaner syntax. So F2 actually gets the addresses of a and b, and then a++ and b++ operate on the original variables defined in main().

Comment: when a and b gets the addresses the a++ and b++ should operate on the addresses or isn't it should be like *a++ or *b++

Comment: You can understand references as follows: If a is a reference, then you can imagine that a stands for (*p) where p is a pointer. So in fact a++ is the same as (*p)++.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're after passing a float pointer to the function

```
void F1(float a, float b)
{
    a++;b++;
}

void F2 (float* a, float* b)
{
    a++;
    b++;
}

int main()
{
    float a, b;
    a = 5;
    b = 7;
    F1(a, b);
    // a is still 5 and b 7
    F2(&a, &b);
    // a is 6 b is 8
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I am passing values and in the definition receiving address

Comment: This is a question for stack overflow then